# WatchKit Error Took too long to show custom notification. Falling back to static

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, watchkit

When I run WatchKit Extension app in my simulator I got following error:

```
Took too long to show custom notification. Falling back to `static`.
```

Can any one tell me why this issue occurs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

99% of the time the reason this happens is that your dynamic notification interface is taking too long to load. Make sure you do only the bare minimum in the initialization methods.